# How to solve the error "do_package: ... not shipped in any package"?

Tags: linux, build, embedded, yocto

At work, I've been facing an error during an SDK build using krogoth branch to an internal machine aimed to x86 architecture, the following description summarizes it:

```
ERROR: nativesdk-flatbuffers-1.12.0-r0 do_package: QA Issue: nativesdk-flatbuffers: Files/directories were installed but not shipped in any package:
  /opt/art/3.0.52.2/sysroots/x86_64-artsdk-linux/usr/lib/cmake
  /opt/art/3.0.52.2/sysroots/x86_64-artsdk-linux/usr/lib/cmake/flatbuffers
  /opt/art/3.0.52.2/sysroots/x86_64-artsdk-linux/usr/lib/cmake/flatbuffers/FlatbuffersTargets.cmake
  /opt/art/3.0.52.2/sysroots/x86_64-artsdk-linux/usr/lib/cmake/flatbuffers/FlatbuffersSharedTargets.cmake
  /opt/art/3.0.52.2/sysroots/x86_64-artsdk-linux/usr/lib/cmake/flatbuffers/FlatbuffersConfig.cmake
  /opt/art/3.0.52.2/sysroots/x86_64-artsdk-linux/usr/lib/cmake/flatbuffers/FlatbuffersTargets-release.cmake
  /opt/art/3.0.52.2/sysroots/x86_64-artsdk-linux/usr/lib/cmake/flatbuffers/FlatbuffersConfigVersion.cmake
  /opt/art/3.0.52.2/sysroots/x86_64-artsdk-linux/usr/lib/cmake/flatbuffers/FlatcTargets-release.cmake
  /opt/art/3.0.52.2/sysroots/x86_64-artsdk-linux/usr/lib/cmake/flatbuffers/FlatcTargets.cmake
  /opt/art/3.0.52.2/sysroots/x86_64-artsdk-linux/usr/lib/cmake/flatbuffers/FlatbuffersSharedTargets-release.cmake
Please set FILES such that these items are packaged. Alternatively if they are unneeded, avoid installing them or delete them within do_install.
nativesdk-flatbuffers: 10 installed and not shipped files. [installed-vs-shipped]
ERROR: nativesdk-flatbuffers-1.12.0-r0 do_package: Fatal QA errors found, failing task.
ERROR: nativesdk-flatbuffers-1.12.0-r0 do_package: Function failed: do_package
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /data/opt/art-shell/users/andre.machoski/krogoth/build/hmi-x86/tmp/work/x86_64-nativesdk-artsdk-linux/nativesdk-flatbuffers/1.12.0-r0/temp/log.do_package.2296
ERROR: Task 2782 (virtual:nativesdk:/data/opt/art-shell/users/andre.machoski/krogoth/poky/meta-art-apps/recipes-3rd/flatbuffers/flatbuffers_1.12.0.bb, do_package) failed with exit code '1'
ERROR: hmiapp-belgrano-1.0-r0 do_compile: oe_runmake failed
ERROR: hmiapp-belgrano-1.0-r0 do_compile: Function failed: do_compile (log file is located at /data/opt/art-shell/users/andre.machoski/krogoth/build/hmi-x86/tmp/work/core2-32-art-linux/hmiapp-belgrano/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.2255)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /data/opt/art-shell/users/andre.machoski/krogoth/build/hmi-x86/tmp/work/core2-32-art-linux/hmiapp-belgrano/1.0-r0/temp/log.do_compile.2255
```

I asked a workmate for some help, and he instructed me to fill the recipe with the following content:

```
FILES_nativesdk-${PN} = " ${libdir}/cmake \
                        ${libdir}/cmake/flatbuffers \
                        ${libdir}/cmake/flatbuffers/FlatbuffersTargets.cmake \
                        ${libdir}/cmake/flatbuffers/FlatbuffersSharedTargets.cmake \
                        ${libdir}/cmake/flatbuffers/FlatbuffersConfig.cmake \
                        ${libdir}/cmake/flatbuffers/FlatbuffersTargets-release.cmake \
                        ${libdir}/cmake/flatbuffers/FlatbuffersConfigVersion.cmake \
                        ${libdir}/cmake/flatbuffers/FlatcTargets-release.cmake \
                        ${libdir}/cmake/flatbuffers/FlatcTargets.cmake \
                        ${libdir}/cmake/flatbuffers/FlatbuffersSharedTargets-release.cmake"
```

But it didn't work. How can I solve this issue?

Below is the full recipe (flatbuffers_1.12.0.bb):

```
SUMMARY = "Memory Efficient Serialization Library"
HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/google/flatbuffers"
SECTION = "console/tools"
LICENSE = "Apache-2.0"

PACKAGE_BEFORE_PN = "${PN}-compiler"

RDEPENDS_${PN}-compiler = "${PN}"
RDEPENDS_${PN}-dev += "${PN}-compiler"

LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://LICENSE.txt;md5=3b83ef96387f14655fc854ddc3c6bd57"

SRCREV = "6df40a2471737b27271bdd9b900ab5f3aec746c7"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/google/flatbuffers.git"

# Make sure C++11 is used, required for example for GCC 4.9
CXXFLAGS += "-std=c++11 -fPIC"
BUILD_CXXFLAGS += "-std=gnu++11 -fPIC"

CXXFLAGS_append_class-nativesdk += "-std=c++11 -fPIC"

# BUILD_TYPE=Release is required, otherwise flatc is not installed
EXTRA_OECMAKE += "\
    -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
    -DFLATBUFFERS_BUILD_TESTS=OFF \
    -DFLATBUFFERS_BUILD_SHAREDLIB=ON \
"

inherit cmake

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

FILES_${PN}-compiler = "${bindir}"

BBCLASSEXTEND = "native nativesdk"

FILES_nativesdk-${PN} = " ${libdir}/cmake \
                        ${libdir}/cmake/flatbuffers \
                        ${libdir}/cmake/flatbuffers/FlatbuffersTargets.cmake \
                        ${libdir}/cmake/flatbuffers/FlatbuffersSharedTargets.cmake \
                        ${libdir}/cmake/flatbuffers/FlatbuffersConfig.cmake \
                        ${libdir}/cmake/flatbuffers/FlatbuffersTargets-release.cmake \
                        ${libdir}/cmake/flatbuffers/FlatbuffersConfigVersion.cmake \
                        ${libdir}/cmake/flatbuffers/FlatcTargets-release.cmake \
                        ${libdir}/cmake/flatbuffers/FlatcTargets.cmake \
                        ${libdir}/cmake/flatbuffers/FlatbuffersSharedTargets-release.cmake"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're building for nativesdk or native (or multilib), `${PN}` already contains `nativesdk-` prefix (or `-native` suffix).

Effectively, what you're doing is setting up `FILES_nativesdk-nativesdk-<pkgname>` and obviously, this does not match any package being created.

Either you use `FILES_nativesdk-<pkgname>` or you can also use `FILES_${PN}_class-nativesdk` which will set `FILES_${PN}` with the content you pass it to only when building for nativesdk.

Comment: I did the modifcations indicated, but I still have the same problem.

Comment: Can you check in `nativesdk-flatbuffers`'s `${WORKDIR}/image` where `flatbuffers` directory is and give us its path relative to `${WORKDIR}/image`?

Comment: Sorry, I made some mistake, you were right, the problem was "nativesdk-"